# How to check whether jcr node has property or not?

Tags: aem, jackrabbit, jcr, jcr-sql2

I am retrieving set of nodes from jcr after specific `lastModified` property.
 But for some nodes it dont have `lastModified` property in that case my query have to look for `jcr:createdDate`.
 How it will achieved?
 This is my query

```
SELECT * FROM [nt:base] AS s WHERE [cq:lastModified] > CAST('2014-05-08T17:36:00.400+05:30' AS DATE)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Test for the property absence [looks like that](http://www.day.com/maven/jcr/2.0/6_Query.html#6.7.18%20PropertyExistence):

```
[cq:lastModified] IS NULL
```

Your query could be rewritten to:

```
SELECT *
FROM [nt:base] AS s
WHERE
    [cq:lastModified] > CAST('2014-05-08T17:36:00.400+05:30' AS DATE)
    OR ([cq:lastModified] IS NULL
        AND
        [jcr:created] > CAST('2014-05-08T17:36:00.400+05:30' AS DATE))
```

Comment: Don't you feel that the check for NULL is unnecessary and the query would return the same result without that too??

Comment: In this particular case it's true, but sridhar asked how to check if given property has no value. The answer may be useful in other situations, when we don't have a second "helper* property like `jcr:created`.

Comment: Thanks but is there any way to use "case when" and "if else " as same as "sql"

Comment: Thanks.But my question here is node which doesn't have a property in this case the property is lastModified not its value.Correct me if am wrong

Answer (score 2):

I think using an OR condition should work for your case, as the node whose lastModified is not greater than the specified date obviously wouldn't have the createdDate greater than it.

And in case the lastModified is not present, it would check for the createdDate and generate the results accordingly

```
SELECT * FROM [nt:base] AS s 
WHERE [cq:lastModified] > CAST('2014-05-08T17:36:00.400+05:30' AS DATE) 
OR [jcr:created] > CAST('2014-05-08T17:36:00.400+05:30' AS DATE)
```